# Create vector and stuck automated in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, vector, stack

I'm creating a program where vector created automatically by code in a function.
My function take data from client. If client specifies that is from Tirana City my function must generate a stuck to save and manipulate data.  Else, if my cleint is from Prishtina my function will generate a simple vector to manipulate data.
So, mostly i want a function that some vector to 
have behavior as a stack,some other not.
How to specifie automated that a vector is a stack in php?

Comment: please select only one language. or do you need it in three languages (i count mysql as well)? please add some examples.

Comment: i will take data from database

Comment: please add some examples. and the structure from the db request as well.

Comment: These are fundamental data structures. This is not the place to be asked for tutorials for them. The web is swarming with them already.

Comment: mostly i want to specifie if a vector wiill be a stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote you are going to create STACK-LIFO, means pop will remove last element, and get confused so I wrote remove first and last you make your own .... but following are the key things

```
<?php
$stack = [];
echo '<pre>';
array_push($stack,1);
print_r($stack);
array_push($stack,2);
print_r($stack);
array_push($stack,3);
// to remove last element
array_splice($stack, count($stack)-1,1);

print_r($stack);

// to remove first element
array_splice($stack, 0,1);
print_r($stack);
```

Comment: mostly i want to specifie if a vector wiill be a stack

Answer (score 0):

If i got you correctly, you can use `array_shift` to get the first element (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$fruit = array_shift($stack);
print_r($stack);

Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
    [2] => raspberry
)

And "orange" is assigned to $fruit
```

To append, you can use `array_push` (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple");
print_r($stack);

Array
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
)
```

Comment: mostly i want to specifie if a vector wiill be a stack